# как удалить пустую строку из листа пайтон

Tags: python, list, список

к примеру ест код `list = [12,3,1,'',99,7,120]`
как удалить пустой элемент ?

Comment: `lst = [i for i in lst if i != '']`

Comment: Мистер @entithat, отмечу от себя, что в вашем варианте исходный список изменен не будет. Будет создан новый.

Comment: @A_Vaclav, ну и хорошо, зачем терять данные, хоть и пустые

Comment: @entithat Так же будут удалены все найденные элементы, а не один...

Comment: @A_Vaclav, ну так, тут уже уточнять надо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, если нужно удалить сразу и пустые строки, и нули, и пустые коллекции, и значения `False`, в общем всё "пустое" одним махом:

```
lst = [12,3,1,'',99,7,120]
print(list(filter(None, lst)))

# [12, 3, 1, 99, 7, 120]
```

Ну или ладно, пусть только пустые строки удалять нужно:

```
lst = [12,3,1,'',99,7,120]
print(list(filter(''.__ne__, lst)))

# [12, 3, 1, 99, 7, 120]
```

Answer (score 3):

**list.remove(x)** - Удаляет первый элемент в списке, имеющий значение x. ValueError, если такого элемента не существует.
[Справка.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
def remove_in_list(arr, template):
    try:
        res = arr[::]# не будем мутировать входные данные
        res.remove(template)
    except ValueError:
        #pass
        print('Элемента нет в списке')
        res = arr
    return res

# Проверим как работает
arr = [12,3,1,'',99,7,120]
arr = remove_in_list(arr, '')
print(arr)

arr = remove_in_list(arr, '')
print(arr)
```

Выводит:

```
[12, 3, 1, 99, 7, 120]
Элемента нет в списке
[12, 3, 1, 99, 7, 120]
```

И вариант без try...except, для "начинающих":

```
def remove_in_list_not_try(arr, template):
    if template in arr:
        res = arr[::]# не будем мутировать входные данные
        res.remove(template)
    else:
        #pass
        print('Элемента нет в списке')
        res = arr
    return res

# Проверим как работает
arr = [12,3,1,'',99,7,120]
arr = remove_in_list_not_try(arr, '')
print(arr)

arr = remove_in_list_not_try(arr, '')
print(arr)
```